# If session cookie not exists CodeIgniter return error on model query

Tags: codeigniter, session, fpdf

I have a CI application that works in the Browser and ElectronJS, I am using FPDF to generate some reports, but I have a problem when a I need to open the PDF from ElectronJS to Internet Explorer or Chrome. If I launch PDF link from Electron I get and syntax error on model query. But if I login using the browser and relaunch the PDF everything works well, It looks like the problem is the session that not exists in browser... but I don't have idea how to solve this problem. Can someone help me?

Electron app
[image]

Browser error after launch the PDF from Electron
[image]

Sorry for my English, regards...

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing any code, but a simple inspection to your DB error shows what the problem is:

`where a.codigolocal= and adddate(...)`

See how the `a.codigolocal=` constraint doesn't have anything after the `=` sign and goes straight to the next `and` clause?
This is very likely because what you are passing as an argument to that constraint comes from the session cookie. No cookie, null value, syntax error.

You need to make sure you have all the data you need (either by checking there's an active session before running the query, or by making sure your query doesn't depend on a session variable that may or may not be there)

Comment: Thanks @Javier Larroulet, you have aa expert eye, and it was a simple solution, thank you so much... regards

Comment: My pleasure! glad you got it to work... remember to upvote! :)